Is there a way to navigate to a custom list view that I created using list views in salesforce on click of a button using lwc?
I have created a list view in a custom object. I want to navigate to this list view with the click of a custom button or action on another related object.
eg: I have custom objects A and B related via lookup. I have created list views on B object based on object A's name field. I have a custom action button on the record page of object A. On clicking this button, I want to navigate to the associated list view in object B.
I have obtained the name field of the record using getFieldValue().
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'standard__objectPage',
            attributes: {
                objectApiName: 'objectB__c',
                actionName: 'list'
            },
            state:{
                filterName: 'Recent'
            }
        });

This code helps me go to the Recent List view. But how to go to a custom list view I created?

You need to use the filterName state parameter with the unique ID of the custom list view.
this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
      type: "standard__objectPage",
      attributes: {
        objectApiName: "objectB__c",
        actionName: "list",
      },
      state: {
        // 'filterName' is a property on the page 'state'
        // and identifies the target list view.
        // It may also be an 18 character list view id.
        filterName: "00BT0000002TONQMA4", // 18 char '00BT0000002TONQMA4'
      },
    });

For more information see this documentation.

Thanks it worked when i gave filterName as listview name. Is there any way to obtain list view id?

You can obtain ListViewID using the following query:
[SELECT Id, Name, DeveloperName, SobjectType FROM ListView];
Once you retrieve the ListViewID, you can store it in an attribute and pass it to the LWC component.
